# Extra symbol in flask and mongodb output

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

My flask code is :

```
from flask import Flask

from flask.ext.pymongo import MongoClient

conn=MongoClient('127.0.0.1',27017)


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/mongo1")
def find():
    dbTest=conn['test']
    dbDocs=[]

    for fruit in dbTest['fruits'].find():
        dbDocs.append(fruit)
    return str(dbDocs)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "hello world!"

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run()
```

I got output in my browser is :

```
[{u'_id': ObjectId('56ea449949b93626b14e2043'), u'name': u'apple'}, {u'_id': ObjectId('56ea444249b93626b14e2040'), u'name': u'apple', u'displayOrder': 1.0}, {u'_id': ObjectId('56ea446549b93626b14e2042'), u'name': u'banana', u'displayOrder': 2.0}, {u'_id': ObjectId('56ea445649b93626b14e2041'), u'name': u'orange', u'displayOrder': 3.0}, {u'_id': ObjectId('56ea7b03fae6cf4cb8d84635'), u'name': u'pinepple'}]
```

My question is why I am getting "u" before every key value pair ?
What should do to ignore such symbol ?

Comment: Try using it on top of PyPy instead of PyPy3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'u' is an indication that they are unicode string. Since you are converting them to string via `str()`. See [Python Unicode encode/decode](http://pythoncentral.io/python-unicode-encode-decode-strings-python-2x/) for more information on this.

Having said that, you could also convert it to JSON:

```python
from bson import json_util

@app.route("/mongo1")
def find():
    dbTest=conn['test']
    dbDocs=[]
    for fruit in dbTest['fruits'].find():
        dbDocs.append(fruit)
    return json_util.dumps(dbDocs)
```

Note that the snippet above is using `bson` module to convert to json instead of `json` module because it needs to be able to decode MongoDB [ObjectID](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).